# iMacros solutions or alternatives for php scripting in MAMP

Tags: php, com, mamp, imacros

So basically I would like to call an iMacro script from a web browser (via url) using PHP in a MAMP environment. This requires the use of the built in `COM` class which is for use in Windows only. I need a solution or alternative to do what I need...anyone know of anything?

I would be looking for either an alternative plugin of iOpus iMacros that supports PHP scripting and doesn't require `COM` or some type of workaround for iMacros that doesn't use `COM`.

Comment: What are you using macros to do?

Comment: When a form is completed on a website it initiates (via php) an imacro script that fills out a form on a service we use. The form is used to generate a report. The form can only be filled out using a macro that simulates user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the details of what site you're interacting with, it's almost certainly possible to interact with it without getting a real browser involved. Without knowing exactly what the site is, it's impossible to say what will work best, but sniffing the contents of HTTP requests using a tool like Firebug or the Chrome Inspector will do you a lot of good.

Once you know what the necessary requests look like, the PHP `curl` extension is the best way to perform them.

Comment: Not sure if you read my comment above. The process will start at a web page containing a sign-up form. When the form is completed it needs to trigger a macro process. I have to use a macro because I can't use php to fill out a 3rd party website form obviously.

Comment: Yes, you can use PHP for that! All a web browser does is submit HTTP requests. There's nothing about that which you can't duplicate with PHP.

Comment: hmm, I think I missed something incredibly fundamental here...so you're saying something like this is totally up my alley? http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Selenium is more oriented towards automated testing. I wouldn't recommend it here.

Comment: Filling out the form involves entering data from a spreadsheet and clicking through many pages of buttons. For example, I enter a domain into an input box and hit submit, then hit the "next" button 4 more times, one for each page. You're saying this can still be done through PHP curl's?

Comment: Also, it has to uncheck a checkbox before submission as well.

Comment: Yes. **There is nothing fundamentally magic about a web browser.** All that a web browser is doing is submitting HTTP requests. curl can do that too.

Comment: I've taken your advice and studied HTTP requests closely and yes you were right all along, but you knew that already :) I've got things working as I wanted using curl requests, thanks!